# Passing VPC from one CDK stack to another

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I am having trouble getting a VPC ID from my shared infrastructure stack to another stack for creating an EC2 instance. Specifically, my error is:

```
AttributeError: type object 'property' has no attribute '__jsii_type__'
```

when calling ec2.Instance

Example code

app.py

```
app = cdk.App()
vpc_stack = VpcStack(app, "VpcStack")
ec2_stack = EC2Stack(app, "EC2Stack", vpc=vpc_stack.vpc)
```

ec2_stack.py

```
class EC2Stack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, *, vpc=ec2.Vpc, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        ec2.Instance(self, "Instance",
                     vpc=vpc.vpc_id,
                     instance_type=ec2.InstanceType("t3.nano"),
                     machine_image=ec2.MachineImage.latest_amazon_linux()
        )
```

vpc_stack.py

```
class VpcStack(Stack):
    vpc = ec2.Vpc
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        vpcName = "MAIN"
        vpcCidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
        natAMI = ec2.GenericLinuxImage({'us-east-2': 'ami-0f9c61b5a562a16af'})

        natInstance = ec2.NatProvider.instance(instance_type=ec2.InstanceType("t3.micro"),machine_image=natAMI)

        vpc = ec2.Vpc(self, str(vpcName), cidr=str(vpcCidr), nat_gateway_provider=natInstance, nat_gateways=1)
```

I would like to be able to pull the VPC ID into my EC2 stack, to start with, although the ability to share resources across stacks in general is the end goal.

I have tried following the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/stack_how_to_create_multiple_stacks.html#cdk-how-to-create-multiple-stacks-define-stack) as well as this other wise very helpful blog post [here](https://towardsthecloud.com/aws-cdk-share-resources-across-stacks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting your `vpc_stack.py` file to look like

```py
class VpcStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        vpcName = "MAIN"
        vpcCidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
        natAMI = ec2.GenericLinuxImage({'us-east-2': 'ami-0f9c61b5a562a16af'})
        natInstance = ec2.NatProvider.instance(instance_type=ec2.InstanceType("t3.micro"),machine_image=natAMI)
        self.vpc = ec2.Vpc(self, str(vpcName), cidr=str(vpcCidr), nat_gateway_provider=natInstance, nat_gateways=1)
```

Then make sure you're using the `Vpc` object on your EC2 instance

```py
class EC2Stack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, *, vpc=ec2.Vpc, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        ec2.Instance(self, "Instance",
            vpc=vpc,  # <- vpc instead of vpc.vpc_id
            instance_type=ec2.InstanceType("t3.nano"),
            machine_image=ec2.MachineImage.latest_amazon_linux()
        )
```

Comment: That worked! I also had to adjust the Ec2 instance to calling the vpc object instead of the vpc_id member as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Edited my answer to include. Thanks!

Comment: Don't understand this solution. You create an instance var called 'self.vpc' in VpcStack and somehow it is known in EC2Stack. How does that work?

Comment: @BertC In the `app.py` file the vpc is being passed as a parameter to the `EC2Stack` (notice the args in `__init__()`).